# Non-parameteric test on 2*2 contingency table

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I got a data that can be categorized in two different ways and I like to test their association. The initial thought is Chi-squared test. However, the data is not normally distributed. What is the prefered test on such non-normally distributed contingency table?

Comment: contingency tables are counts; you should be fine to use a chi-squared test on  2x2 table of counts as long as none of the expected values are quite small.

Comment: What if my data is not normally distributed? Would that violate the chi-squared distribution assumption?